# Don't map a list if it's undefined

Tags: reactjs

In the following snippet I define a list and an object state. The object that changes according to the input adds the value of the current object to the list as soon as the button is clicked. However, what I want to do here is that when the list is empty, the div is not created and the map function does not work. You will see below that I tried to solve this using the ternary operator, but I couldn't.

[view of the main app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9EMg.png)

```
function Form() {
    let key = 1
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
        enteredName: '',
        enteredAge: '',
        key: key
    })
    const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);
    const nameChange = (e) => {
        setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredName: e.target.value });
    }
    const ageChange = (e) => {
        setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredAge: e.target.value });
    }
    const pompa = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setData((prev) => {
            return [userInput, ...prev]
        })
        key++;
        setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredName: "", enteredAge: "" });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <div className="form">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <br />
                    <input className="input" type="text" required value={userInput.enteredName} onChange={nameChange}></input>
                    <br />
                    <label>Age</label>
                    <br />
                    <input className="input" type="text" value={userInput.enteredAge} onChange={ageChange}></input>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button className="button" onClick={pompa}> Add User</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br />
            {data === undefined ? console.log("Empty") :
                <div id="liste">
                    <ul>
                        {data.map((number) =>

                            <li key={number.id}>
                                <div>{number.enteredName + " "}{number.enteredAge}</div>
                            </li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't see how `data` can ever be undefined. Undefined is not the same as empty. An empty array will not interfere with `map`, it just won't need to do an iteration

Comment: The problem you're more likely experiencing is due to the initialization of an array that **is not empty** but contains one value - an empty object (`[{}]`). The empty object **will** cause an iteration with `map` and will cause issues because it does not have the properties `enteredName` and `enteredAge`. Just remove the object from your initial state and use a truly empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state is an array of objects, you just need to check the `length` of that array like this and remove the empty object `{}` of your initial state value:

```
function Form() {
    let key = 1
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
        enteredName: '',
        enteredAge: '',
        key: key
    })
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const nameChange = (e) => {
        setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredName: e.target.value });
    }
    const ageChange = (e) => {
        setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredAge: e.target.value });
    }
    const pompa = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setData((prev) => {
            return [userInput, ...prev]
        })
        key++;
        setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredName: "", enteredAge: "" });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <div className="form">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <br />
                    <input className="input" type="text" required value={userInput.enteredName} onChange={nameChange}></input>
                    <br />
                    <label>Age</label>
                    <br />
                    <input className="input" type="text" value={userInput.enteredAge} onChange={ageChange}></input>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button className="button" onClick={pompa}> Add User</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br />
            {data.length > 0 ?
                <div id="liste">
                    <ul>
                        {data.map((number) =>

                            <li key={number.id}>
                                <div>{number.enteredName + " "}{number.enteredAge}</div>
                            </li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            : console.log("Empty")}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: How will this do anything different? The **initial** state has a length of 1. Your answer is in general good advice, but won't help the OP here.

Comment: You just need to set your initial value as `[]` array don't need the empty object

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `useState([{}])` you initialize `data` with an array with one empty object, so `data === undefined` will never yield `true`.

Instead initialize it with an empty array with `useState([])` and check against `data.length === 0`.